# influxDB and cadvisor integration issue

Tags: docker, influxdb, cadvisor

I want to access to the gathered data from cadvisor through influxdb 
here my docker configurations:

```
//for cadvisor
docker run     
--volume=/:/rootfs:ro     
--volume=/var/run:/var/run:rw     
--volume=/sys:/sys:ro     
--volume=/var/lib/docker/:/var/lib/docker:ro     
--publish=8080:8080     
--detach=true     
--name=cadvisorDB     
google/cadvisor:latest     
-storage_driver=influxdb     
-storage_driver_host=127.0.0.1:8086
-storage_driver_db=databaseName

//for InfluxDB
docker run 
-d 
-p 8083:8083 
-p 8086:8086 
--expose 8090 
--expose 8099 
tutum/influxdb
//and I created manually the databse through the WEB UI on localhost:8083   
with the name databaseName`
```

So once I start the two containers, I go to the influxDB to explore data (by making a query). An error says that there is no data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything in the configuration looks fine. The problem is probably in this line:

> -storage_driver_host=127.0.0.1:8086

because 127.0.0.1 is refering to cadvisor container localhost and not your localhost. Try to put instead docker Nat ip (usually 172.17.42.1).

Answer (score 2):

This is what I use in my "docker-compose" YAML file. Should be very easy to translate to the usual "docker run" syntax. In my case I'm linking the InfluxDB container in cAdvisor, so cAdvisor knows how to resolve the hostname "influxdb" regardless of the internal Docker IP assigned to the container.

```css
influxdb:
  image: tutum/influxdb
  hostname: influxdb
  volumes:
    - ./influxdb:/data
  environment:
    - PRE_CREATE_DB=cadvisor
  ports:
    - "8083:8083"
    - "8086:8086"
  expose:
    - "8090"
    - "8099"

cadvisor:
  image: google/cadvisor
  hostname: cadvisor
  volumes:
    - /:/rootfs:ro
    - /var/run:/var/run:rw
    - /sys:/sys:ro
    - /var/lib/docker:/var/lib/docker:ro
  ports:
    - "8089:8080"
  links:
    - influxdb
  command: -storage_driver_db=cadvisor -storage_driver_host=influxdb:8086
```

NOTE: InfluxDB can create your DB automatically if you set the **PRE_CREATE_DB** environment variable.